# Does Minecraft require a constant Internet connection?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My son has played the small version of Minecraft on an Android tablet and wants the full version (either PC or Xbox 360), but we do not have Internet access at home. Will he be able to play the game?

Answer (score 2):

You can play both versions' games offline, however you need internet access to initially download them. For the PC version you can download the files needed onto a thumb drive and plug it into the computer. For the 360 version, though. there is no easy way to get it without internet access.

If you need help getting the files over don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: They do sell an Xbox 360 version on disc of Minecraft at retail stores: Best Buy, etc.

Comment: oh really? I thought those were just codes to download it. That's a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the files, you or your son could play singleplayer without internet. If he wanted to play with friends or something, you would have to have internet for that.

Note: If you get Minecraft for Xbox 360, there is a splitscreen capability that he could play with friends if they were at your house.